# Customization of react Amplify UI Authenticator Component

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, authenticator

I'm using the Amplify UI Authenticator component for the Authentication and added social Provider login also. Is there any way to customize the component. I Want the Social Provider buttons after the Sign in button.

```
<Authenticator
                loginMechanisms={["email"]}
                formFields={formFields}
                components={components}
                socialProviders={["google", "facebook", "amazon", "apple"]}
              />
```

[image: Sign In Page]

Comment: Can you change the order [here](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization#sign-up-field-order)?

Comment: @Luke , Yes I'm able to change that by adding the css file with below style.            [data-amplify-form]{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

Comment: So, has your issue been resolved?

Comment: Yes, It is Resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can review the [customization](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization#sign-up-field-order) options here, where you can edit your CSS.

```
 [data-amplify-form]{ display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; }
```